# Playing QSound in Qt for Mac after using macdeployqt

Tags: qt, macos

I was originally playing a QSound that was located in the Resources folder in the app bundle. After running macdeployqt, the sound will no longer play. I have already checked to see that wav file is still the the Resources folder. Has anyone ever dealt with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [QSound documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsound.html#details), you'll read this :

> Note that QSound does not support resources. This might be fixed in a future Qt version.

This sentence has been in the docs for ages now, and as I'm writing this (Qt 4.7), this still haven't been fixed.

I guess your best workaround is to put your sound as a separate file (I haven't go much experience with Mac, but maybe you can put your sound file in your app bundle) and handle the file path by yourselft when creating a `QSound` object.

Comment: I think that comment refers to the embedded resources (i.e. qrc file), not the Resources directory within an application bundle, which is just another directory.